# React-Native: How to foreground the remote debugger tab?

Tags: android, react-native

I run my react-native app with expo go on a actual android device. The react-native app is only opening a WebView so far. That's working.

But somehow it doesn't always load the full page, it sometimes get's stuck at the custom loading spinner of my page. To see why, I want to see the `console.log` statements of my website. So I enabled the developer mode on my android device and then when running the app I shook the device to get the developer menu. I clicked on `Debug Remote JS` and the app reloads.

Then I see warnings showing up in my Visual-Studio terminal where I started the app on my laptop.

How can I get the background tab into the foreground or how would I see the console logs? Also what could be the reason of the additional error message: "Error getting device logs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined at matchFileNameOrURLFromStackTrace"

```
Remote debugger is in a background tab which may cause apps to perform slowly. Fix this by foregrounding the tab (or opening it in a separate window).
at http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:73124:22 in registerWarning
at http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:73061:26 in warnImpl
at http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:73038:15 in console.warn
at http://127.0.0.1:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false:107137:17 in warn
Error getting device logs: TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at matchFileNameOrURLFromStackTrace (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\src\utils\matchFileNameOrURLFromStackTrace.ts:16:42)
    at logStackTrace (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:549:31)
    at logWithLevel (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:585:11)
    at Object.write (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:657:13)
    at Logger._emit (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\bunyan\lib\bunyan.js:928:22)
    at Logger.warn (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\bunyan\lib\bunyan.js:1053:24)
    at handleDeviceLogs (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\src\middleware\clientLogsMiddleware.ts:81:21)
    at C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\src\middleware\clientLogsMiddleware.ts:28:7
    at call (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:239:7)
    at next (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:183:5)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at matchFileNameOrURLFromStackTrace (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\src\utils\matchFileNameOrURLFromStackTrace.ts:16:42)
    at logStackTrace (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:549:31)
    at logWithLevel (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:585:11)
    at Object.write (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\src\exp.ts:657:13)
    at Logger._emit (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\bunyan\lib\bunyan.js:928:22)
    at Logger.warn (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\bunyan\lib\bunyan.js:1053:24)
    at handleDeviceLogs (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\src\middleware\clientLogsMiddleware.ts:81:21)
    at C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\dev-server\src\middleware\clientLogsMiddleware.ts:28:7
    at call (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:239:7)
    at next (C:\Users\(secret)\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v14.15.4\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\connect\index.js:183:5)
```